# Motherboard BIOS does not recognize nvme ssd

Tags: ssd, bios, nvme

I am using a Gigabyte Aorus Gaming 5 Wifi Motherboard and a Crucial P1 NVME SSD. When I enter the BIOS the system does not recognize any bootable drives and I cannot get it to recognize it so I can download windows. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

it seems most likely that you have it plugged in to the wrong slot. On that board, there are 2 M.2 slots that will fit your SSD, but only 1 of those support NVME. You want to plug it in to the one labeled M2A_Socket. Make sure you read the manual carefully, as they mention it there but it's in the fineprint.

Comment: I just switched the slot. Is it safe to install a gpu above an ssd?

Comment: I have moved the slot into the m2a_socket but at still not recognized in bios. Is there a setting that has to be enabled?

Comment: Check the Manual that comes with the Motherboard, or online at Gigabyte's website if you don't have a manual, it will tell you what settings to use. It may be possible that you have to update the BIOS or change some settings. Only other thing that comes to mind is make sure you have RAID turned off, and make sure that m2a_socket is not using AHCI, make sure that Nvma support is turned on. The SSD you have is also not on the motherboard's official supported list, though that usually isn't an issue, but you never know.

Comment: I am using RAID not AHCI where is the option for making sure nvme support is on in the Gigabyte Bios?

Comment: RAID mode is likely the problem.  Change it to AHCI and try again.